# Login/Registration functionality in cq5

Tags: web-services, rest, osgi, aem

I need to create register/login functionality in CQ5. There are three ways

1 - The register/login functionality should be  prepared as web service hosted on a Java Application Server and then we can consume data from web services.

2 - The functionality should be  prepared as web service based on RESTFull that hosted on CQ itself since AEM is developed around the REST principal and REST web services is certainly one which will be supported. So I believe RESTfull web services can be hosted with CQ5.

3 - Why do we need web services? I do not think it requires web services since my application is not going to communicate with other application and it dont want to expose any services to outside world. Why don't we create register/login functionality as we do in normal web application. Can we create a OSGI bundle that invoke databases to store user details for register/login functionality?

I would go for 3rd option but my concern is AEM is not the place to build our business logic to carry out functions that are not related to content rendering.

which option would you choose and why? Kindly share your ideas and thoughts. I am just looking for best solution to develop register/login functionality in CQ.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think i am late to the party but it might help someone. Yes, you can very well create rest webservices in CQ and they work well. So, you can take that approach.

The way to go about implementing login/registration would be how it is done OOTB but OOTB is also bad in the way it implements it so you have to make modifications to overcome that.

1) You need to register and Authentication handler with CQ. If you are looking for a sample there is a form authentication handler source that you can look at.

2) We have integrated out Auth handler with Active Directory (AD). Since AD is supported by default, so it is easy to integrate with Auth Handlers.

3) Next you need to create a user login token for which you can look into TokenUtil class of CQ or if you are looking to develop SSO, you can look into SSO code that is packaged OOTB.